# django_auth_adfs: get JWT token for the client on successful authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory, django-authentication, azure-authentication

I have a `Django` application that doesn't have MVC pages and most of the data is served/posted via restful API powered by `django-rest-framework`. My userbase is in Azure single tenant AD, so I am trying to get the SSO going for them.

I am using `django_auth_adfs` to authenticate users against the Azure AD. Most of the stuff seems to work and the module takes care of the redirects and establishing the Django sessions for the client. Specifying the right `permission_classes` for the API `ViewSets` will make sure only authenticated users can access it it works fine via browser with proper django session cookie.

What I can't figure out is how to get the JWT token that I can give the UI client so that it could interact with the `django-rest-framework` API by supplying the JWT bearer and not relying on the session.

[The documentation](https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_framework.html) is not very specific on these details (besides the password grant that isn't quite relevant for my scenario).

Comment: I am not married to `django_auth_adfs` if there is a better option, I have tried a couple of other libs and this one seems to work better than others.

Comment: I actually am in the exact same boat, so curious to what others suggest. My initial thought is to just have a single session authed page to be called by the UI client and returns the JWT, which will be used for all subsequent API calls. This seems really like a hack to me thou...

Comment: Could it work for you with the sessionid?